# scrutinizerCI : is there a way to set up multiple project analysis per repository?

Tags: scrutinizer

Working with a monorepo with the following structure :

packages
packA
packB
apps
appA
appB

Currently, we use scrutinizerCI as an external analysis tool and the analysis is done globally as is the coverage.

Tried to duplicate the repo but there is no "path" to configure which file are actually analyzed

Comment: is this he central scrutinizer?

Comment: You mean https://scrutinizer-ci.com? that's what we use